# IIS Virtual Directory Error After Service Pack Update

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server that was recently updated to SP1. For some reason this SP update broke a virtual directory hosted via IIS on that server. This virtual directory is pointed to a folder that houses some JPEG images. There's no website with it. Just a web.config file in a folder with 100 images. The server is on IIS version 7.5.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSiou.png) is the error we get now.

Below is the entire contents of the web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. For some reason with Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 a Virtual Directory must be converted to an Application before it will work. Once I converted it to an application it worked just fine.